# Uninstall docker command didn't get docker removed

Tags: docker

So when I according to https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/ run following command

```
sudo yum remove docker \
                  docker-client \
                  docker-client-latest \
                  docker-common \
                  docker-latest \
                  docker-latest-logrotate \
                  docker-logrotate \
                  docker-engine
```

the printed message is

```
no match for argument docker; 
no match for argument docker-client
...(all the argument listed)
```

And also,after I run the command above, the docker is still there, it is not get uninstalled. When I run `docker version` it tell me the docker client version is `18.03.1-ce`

I also tried `sudo yum remove docker-ce`,same thing.

What should I do to remove old docker?

Or I don't have to worry, just install the latest version? But by the site's link it tells me to first remove existing docker then install new one.

My system is centos 7.4

When I run `yum list installed` I didn't find any docker related file.
Is that means the docker installed in the machine is not managed by yum ? And it can't get removed by yum.